# How to get a GNUmakefile to recognize CFLAGS option for -std=c99 or -std=gnu99?

Tags: objective-c, makefile, gnustep

I'm trying to compile a GNUstep program with the compiler option either c99 or gnu99, but it isn't being recognized ... here is my makefile:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = triangular
triangular_C_FLAGS = -std=gnu99
triangular_HEADERS =
triangular_OBJC_FILES = main.m
triangular_RESOURCE_FILES =

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the output from make:

```
This is gnustep-make 2.6.0. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Making all for tool triangular...
 Compiling file main.m ...
main.m: In function 'main':
main.m:18:3: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

main.m:18:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make[3]: *** [obj/triangular.obj/main.m.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [internal-tool-all_] Error 2
make[1]: *** [triangular.all.tool.variables] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

Comment: You're not giving us enough information to go on. What happens when you try to run this? And what do `tool.make` and `common.make` look like?

Comment: I added the output from make. tool.make and common.make are big makefiles that are included with the GNUstep environment.

Comment: It's saying there's a problem in `main.m`, line 18. If the bug isn't obvious, try isolating that scrap of code in a `helloWorld` and compiling by hand, without Make.

Comment: @beta - line 18 of `main.m` will have something like `for (int i=0; i<10; ++i){`, which while illegal in c89 is valid in c99. The issue seems to be getting the `-std=gnu99` flag to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

`ADDITIONAL_FLAGS += -std=gnu99`
worked for me
(inspired by https://github.com/maddox/regexkit/blob/master/GNUstep/GNUmakefile

Answer (score 0):

At first glance and without knowing the contents of the included makefiles this looks like input for `automake`, which converts the variables into proper rules. How are you running your makefile? Are you just running `make` or `automake makefile.am` or something else?

One thing to try is to just add the line

```
CFLAGS+=-std=gnu99
```

to your makefile.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm just running make. I tried the above and still get the error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about GNUstep, but [the documentation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/make_1.html#SEC16) seems to indicate that you should use `triangular_CFLAGS` (without the underscore between C and FLAGS).

Besides, I know even less about ObjC, but I'm wondering if you shouldn't use `triangular_OBJCFLAGS` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another long shot:

```
export triangular_C_FLAGS = -std=gnu99
```

(These makefiles seem to be recursing.) If that doesn't work, you'll have to find the rule that is attempting to build `main.o`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in my project, and using the OBJCFLAGS variable suggested by @eriktous worked for me. So, in your project, try this:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = triangular
triangular_OBJCFLAGS = -std=c99
triangular_HEADERS =
triangular_OBJC_FILES = main.m
triangular_RESOURCE_FILES =

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Maybe add a reference?

Comment: I was attempting to solve a similar problem by applying the tip given by @eriktous in a previous reply to this question. That poster made a reference to the GNUstep [documentation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/make_1.html#SEC16), which mentions the OBJCFLAGS variable. I have edited my original post to show the full makefile.